# SceneKit: Limiting Rotation on Different Axes

Tags: scenekit

I'm using Xcode 8 (beta) with Swift 3, and I'm trying to limit which axes are able to be rotated when moving the camera around a SceneKit world. The camera can be moved around while pointing at the center of the world, and I'd like to only let the x & y axes move, but not z. Here's a clearer [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s0WG.png).

Pitch and Yaw should be adjustable, but not Roll.

```
func setupLightsAndCamera(scene: SCNScene) {
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 30, z: 30)
    cameraNode.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint(target: center)]
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at gimbleLockEnabled?

Comment: It's not perfect, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the code that adjusts the camera position? If control that, you can control its effect on the camera.